# JavaScript - Setting variables

Tags: javascript

In the following JavaScript code, the value that is being returned by function(result) is correct. So I'm seeing two alert views - one with the correct value and the second alert simply returns 1. So my question is - how do I conserve the value of mainResult so that it shows the same output ?

```
var mainResult = 1;
Download.beginDownload(arr,
       function(result){
          mainResult = result;
          alert(result);
          }, function(result){
                alert("here2");
                console.log(result);
          }
 );


alert(mainResult);
```

Comment: Are you expecting `mainResult` to show the same as `result`?

Comment: Your last line is throwing the alert before your callback function has ever run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some sort of Asynchronous call and you are acing like it is synchronous.

The alert is called before the callback happens.

Comment: That is correct. I'm actually using PhoneGap and this is used to make a call to the Objective-C code. But what would be the best way to update the value of mainResult once I get result

Comment: It is updated when the callback is fired. You are just reading it too early.